# Close bootstrap modal back button bootstrap./

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, pushstate

I am building an angularjs app and i am using bootstrap modal.

Once the user hits the back button on his phone,  i want to have him close the modal.

I am using html5mode as off meaning i have the #

I am trying to add history.pushstate(null,null,'modalopened') once the user opens the modal then remove it once the modal closes or the user clicks the back button and navigates backwards.

I understand that the back button on mobile phones will autoamtically move back in the history api.

however when i do that i get redirected back to the root '/#/'

Answer (score 0):

$locationChangeStart fires when user clicks back button, you can attach to the event and do your custom logic of hiding.

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, newUrl, oldUrl) {

      //hide the control

    }
```